# Getting a NoMethodError undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when a button is pressed in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I press the button that has the onclick method "doSomething()" it executes the doSomething() method and then gives me the error of noMethoderror. It tries to go to some_path. I don't want that button to go to some_path - I want it to only execute the javascript function. How can this be solved?

```
= form_for(:set, url: some_path) do |form|
  h1 Create Something

  button onclick="dosomething()" Add something

  div
    = form.label :some_text
    = form.text_field :some_text
  div
    = form.submit

= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the button's type to  type="button" worked. By default slim was parsing it as a submit button.

```
 button type="button"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround might be to use:

```
!= "<button onclick='dosomething()'>Do something</button>"
```

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html